# printable gridview?

Tags: gridview

I have a very big gridview with 30 columns and 10 rows on each page. I have to make this data printable. It is to wide to just print it from browser. What is the best solution?

Making a report (crystal report), making an excel or word file from some datasource..?

Comment: You need to add some meaningful tags. What platform / language ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple things you can do.

1. You can create a CSS style for your grid to be used when media="print"
2. There are some printable GridView controls that a few people have made and posted articles about.  Use your preferred search engine and search for 'printable gridview'